# JavaScript send full HTML source via AJAX, problems with UTF8

Tags: javascript, ajax, utf-8

I'm having troubles with sending a full page source with AJAX. I've tried escaping the content with `escape()`, `encodeURI()`, `encodeURIComponent()` - all of them fail sending utf8 characters.

My code is:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var send = params='html=' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.outerHTML).replace('+',' ');
http.open('POST','submitsource.php',true);
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
http.onreadystatechange=function(){if(http.readyState==4&&http.status==200){
    alert('ok!');
}};

http.send(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tag Meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your content-type to "text/html", and read the entire post data as html on your server

Answer (score 0):

Problem was actually with PHP writing the response into a file. I had to put the UTF-8 signature in front of my content to get it to write without messing up the characters

```
file_put_contents('contents.txt', "\xEF\xBB\xBF".$_POST['html']);
```